# Remote GPU clock skew estimation

Tags: webgl, gpu, clock

I'm trying to estimate the clock skew of a device's GPU through timestamp requests to the GPU. I read that OpenGL has those kind of requests but i'm trying to do it using WebGL.
Does anyone know a way with which I can accomplish that (either getting timestamps from the GPU, or another way to try and estimate the GPU's clock skew using WebGL)?.

Comment: Where did you hear that OpenGL has these kinds of things? You can use a timer query to get a timestamp, but it is completely unrelated to the GPU's clock. It is related to the OpenGL pipeline itself.

Comment: oh sorry. I thought it's related to the GPU's clock. Do you have any Idea how to get timestamps from the GPU's clock?